# How to put the icon inside the React Material Ui text field?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I want to put the eye icon inside the text field which I use as a password but I couldn't find a way to place it inside the text field component in Material UI.
[image]
This is the code;

```
<TextField
        variant="outlined"
        margin="dense"
        required
        fullWidth
        placeholder={placeholder}
        name={label}
        type={showPassword ? "text" : type}
        id={id}
        inputProps={{
          style: {
            background: "white",
            boxShadow: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px",
            height: "15px",
            borderRadius: "10px",
            width: "100%",
            marginRight: 0,
          },
        }}
        InputProps={{
          classes: { notchedOutline: classes.noBorder },
          endAdornment:
            type === "password" ? (
              <InputAdornment
                position="start"
                classes={{ positionStart: "0px" }}
              >
                <IconButton
                  onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                  onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                >
                  {showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            ) : null,
        }}
      />
```

Comment: It is hard to reproduce your code, can you create a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Your adornment settings seem mostly right according to the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#input-adornments). The only issue I can see is that you've set position to start rather than end for the InputAdornment. Also, you're using `classes` wrong. I've included it in the example below but you probably want to remove it from this section entirely.

Try this:

```
   <InputAdornment
-    position="start"
-    classes={{ positionStart: "0px" }}
+    position="end"
+    classes={ 
       positionEnd: {
         marginLeft: 0
       }
     }
    >
```